# Spinners selection changes on adding new items or scrolling listview android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have added two spinners on custom adapter **list view**. All is good but when I add new item to list view then value of previous item's spinner is transformed to new item. And on scrolling **list view** values of spinners also rotates. Any Help please.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<MyMessageDetails> _data;
    Context _c;
     ProductsItemViewHolder holder;
    CustomAdapter (ArrayList<MyMessageDetails> data, Context c){
        _data = data;
        _c = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _data.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View v = convertView;
        final MyMessageDetails msg = _data.get(position);
        if (v == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)_c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, null);
            holder = new ProductsItemViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.fromView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.spinnersizes = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            holder.spinnercopies = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            String Photo_copies[];
            Photo_copies=new String[100];
            int x = 1;
            while( x < 101 ) {
                if(x == 1){
                    Photo_copies[x-1]= String.valueOf(x) + " Copy";
                }else{
                    Photo_copies[x-1]= String.valueOf(x) + " Copies";
                }

                x++;
            }

            String array_spinner[];
            array_spinner=new String[5];
            array_spinner[0]="4x6|Plastic|RS 20";
            array_spinner[1]="option 2";
            array_spinner[2]="option 3";
            array_spinner[3]="option 4";
            array_spinner[4]="option 5";

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(_c,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
            ArrayAdapter adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter(_c,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Photo_copies);
            holder.spinnersizes.setAdapter(adapter);
            holder.spinnercopies.setAdapter(adapter2);
            holder.spinnercopies.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View v, int position, long id) {
                    String sizes = holder.spinnersizes.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    holder.spinnersizes.setTag(position);
                    String copies = holder.spinnercopies.getSelectedItem().toString();                 
                    String  mycopies = copies;
                    String  myprice = sizes;
                    myprice = myprice.substring(myprice.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
                    mycopies = mycopies.substring(0, mycopies.lastIndexOf(" "));
                    int finalprice = Integer.parseInt(myprice) * Integer.parseInt(mycopies);
                    holder.fromView.setText(holder.image.getTag().toString() + " Copies:" + mycopies + " Price:" + finalprice);
                    msg.setCopies(mycopies);
                    msg.setSize(String.valueOf(finalprice));
                    //  lab_gallery.Calculate_Bill();

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

                }

            });

            holder.spinnersizes.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View v, int position, long id) {
                    // your code here
                    String sizes = holder.spinnersizes.getSelectedItem().toString();    
                    holder.spinnersizes.setTag(position);
                    String copies = holder.spinnercopies.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    String  mycopies = copies;
                    String  myprice = sizes;
                    myprice = myprice.substring(myprice.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
                    mycopies = mycopies.substring(0, mycopies.lastIndexOf(" "));
                    int finalprice = Integer.parseInt(myprice) * Integer.parseInt(mycopies);
                    holder.fromView.setText(holder.image.getTag().toString() + " Copies:" + mycopies + " Price:" + finalprice);
                    msg.setCopies(mycopies);
                    msg.setSize(String.valueOf(finalprice));
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

                }

            });
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(msg.getIcon());
            holder.fromView.setTag(msg.getUrl());
            holder.fromView.setText(msg.getName()); 
            holder.image.setTag(msg.getName());
            msg.setCopies("1");
            msg.setSize("20");
            v.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ProductsItemViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }


        if (holder.spinnersizes.getTag() != null){
            holder.spinnersizes.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(holder.spinnersizes.getTag().toString()));
        }

        //image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);


        return v;

    }
    static class ProductsItemViewHolder {

        ImageView image;
        TextView fromView;
        Spinner spinnersizes;
        Spinner spinnercopies;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of view recycling. View are recycled with the last state. If your spinner had something selected, and if that view is reused it'll also pick the state of the spinner. You need to add logic to preserve state of your Spinners. You can maintain a dictionary with row position and selectedIndex.

//Class level field

```
Map<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

inside your getView() method check if we have a state saved for the spinner at this row psition

```
if (myMap.containsKey(position)) {
   spinner.setSelection(myMap.get(position));
}
```

Saving state when an item is selected in spinner

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View v, int selectedIndex, long id) {
//...
 myMap.put(position, selectedIndex);
//...
}
```